# Recovering partition from a linux RAID 1 array

Tags: linux, mdadm, software-raid

I had an old server (Fedora 4-- yes, old!) die recently. It was configured with two IDE disks in a software RAID 1 array, and I'm trying to recover the data. Unfortunately it had been a while since I messed with mdadm and I'm afraid I might have messed something up. Also, although there were two disks in the array, one of them seems outright dead. When I attach it to another machine, that machine hangs at the BIOS screen and won't boot. So I'm down to using the other mirrored disk.

I put the disk in another machine, and the first thing I tried was to run:

`mdadm --create /dev/md0 -v --force --raid-devices=1 --level=raid1 /dev/sdb2`

This however would not let me mount the filesystem:

`# mount -t ext3 /dev/md0 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so`

It did apparently write something back to the disk though, which is why I fear I may have messed it up:

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b6babdfb:e99e3bd3:398fcebe:dd38faab
           Name : bluto:0  (local to host bluto)
  Creation Time : Thu Dec 29 15:36:10 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 1

 Avail Dev Size : 310277362 (147.95 GiB 158.86 GB)
     Array Size : 310277218 (147.95 GiB 158.86 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 310277218 (147.95 GiB 158.86 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 0f3d948b:398095cc:9621f72f:fcd11310

    Update Time : Thu Dec 29 15:36:10 2016
       Checksum : c58ea2b6 - correct
         Events : 0


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

The creation time here is current, and the hostname, "bluto", is the machine I'm using for recovery, not the original server. So that definitely got written during my recovery efforts and makes me worried that something important might have been wiped out.

I then remembered a simpler mdadm trick, and this actually works on a different partition of the same disk. Unfortunately that partition was just /boot, so the data is not interesting, but it proves that the technique should work:

```
# mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
# mount -t ext3 /dev/md0 /mnt
# ls /mnt
config-2.6.11-1.1369_FC4  grub                          initrd-2.6.17-1.2142_FC4.img  System.map-2.6.11-1.1369_FC4  vmlinuz-2.6.11-1.1369_FC4
config-2.6.17-1.2142_FC4  initrd-2.6.11-1.1369_FC4.img  lost+found                    System.map-2.6.17-1.2142_FC4  vmlinuz-2.6.17-1.2142_FC4
```

But when I unmount that and stop the md device, then try the same thing with my actual data partition (sdb2), I get the same error as before:

```
# umount /mnt
# mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: stopped /dev/md0
# mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdb2
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 1 drive.
# mount -t ext3 /dev/md0 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

I'm not sure what to try next here. I thought of running e2fsck on it, but should I run it against /dev/sdb2 directly, or against /dev/md0 when it's running? I'm also worried that this might corrupt things even worse if the fs is already bad.